# In SSRS, how do I force the reporting server locale from English-US to English-GB?

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services

I have an issue where all dates in parameters are displayed as **mm/dd/yyyy**:

[image: SSRS US locale]

My goal is to change the date format to **dd/mm/yyyy**, which would require changing the locale to **English-GB**. Things which I've currently tried (and didn't work):

1. Changing the Language within the individual report settings to **English-GB**
2. Checking the Windows locale setting on the SQL Server instance (it was already set to English-GB and dd/mm/yyyy)
3. Changing the default SQL Server language using `EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23 ;`
4. Changing the Reporting Server's service account language using `ALTER LOGIN [XXXXX] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = British`
5. Restarting the Reporting Service
6. Killing all connections to the SQL Server instance to force a reconnect

Non of the above worked and I'm still seeing the dates in the wrong format. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think actually this comes from the Language of the **browser** rather than Report Server - I could be wrong. Try changing from US English to GB English in IE or whatever you're using.

Comment: Thank you! That was the exact issue.